# JS slider doesn't work after AngularJS migrate from 1.0.8 to 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration, angularjs-ng-route

I'm trying to migrate AnguarJS from 1.0.8 to 1.2 and I have problem with JavaScript slider which does not work after migration...

after changing to 1.2 I added angular-route.js library and injected 'ngRoute' to my module and that couses problems with pure JS slider...

here is plunker example of this issue:
1.0.8 version: http://plnkr.co/edit/l4k3vgbqzHIpCTlzcwr6?p=preview

```
       var app = angular.module("calculatorApplication", []).config(function ($routeProvider) {
```

1.2 version: http://plnkr.co/edit/qhf1YjlXMFwq0X8TgT21?p=preview

```
 var app = angular.module("calculatorApplication", ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
```

thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `slider.html` you have the following:

```
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true
  });
</script>
```

In AngularJS **1.2** scripts inside templates aren't executed when inserted by for example `ng-view` or `ng-include`.

This was however fixed in AngularJS **1.2.2**.

If you can't use **1.2.2** you can move the code into a directive instead.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! IT WORKS!